# Tips for defeating Benezia and her commandos at Noveria

Tags: mass-effect

With less than a year to finish Mass Effect and ME2, I've been grinding my way through.  Right now, though, I'm having some trouble with Benezia.  What are some strategies and associated tactics that should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it through intact.  Standard use of cover and good position saw me through.

Comment: 90% of the battles in Mass Effect 1 can be won with patience. The other 10% are when Rachni sneak up behind you and 1HKO you through your shields.

Comment: Benezia was the boss that gave me the most trouble.  Use cover constantly and always have a place to fall back to.

Comment: The low platform sort of under where she hangs out was one of my favourite places to take cover the first time I fought her (from the door where you enter turn right and it is the first left).

Answer (score 1):

I usually just ignored her (e.g. let the party handle her), and ran around killing commandos. If you let them set up or split up, they can be a real problem, but if you get them while they're grouped around the door, you can turn them into mush without losing your shields. Typically I'd hunker down and pare their numbers with the sniper rifle, then charge in and finish them off at close range.

The only trouble I ever had was that occasionally I'd get knocked off the walkways and be unable to complete the effing mission.